# Upload images to sitecore media library from server

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

How Can I upload images to Sitecore Media Library from a Folder on the server

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath("~/images/temp"));
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
var list = new ArrayList();

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        if (file.Extension == ".jpg" || file.Extension == ".jpeg" || file.Extension == ".gif" || file.Extension == ".png")
        {
            list.Add(file);
        }
    }

// Now I want to add the files to media library in sitecore.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a file to Media library use this method:

```
  public MediaItem AddFile(string fileName, string sitecorePath, string mediaItemName)
{
  // Create the options
   Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions options = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions();
  // Store the file in the database, not as a file
  options.FileBased = false;
  // Remove file extension from item name
  options.IncludeExtensionInItemName = false;
  // Overwrite any existing file with the same name
  options.KeepExisting = false;
  // Do not make a versioned template
  options.Versioned = false;
  // set the path
 options.Destination = sitecorePath + "/" + mediaItemName; 
 // Set the database
 options.Database = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

   // Now create the file
   Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator creator = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator();
   MediaItem mediaItem = creator.CreateFromFile(filename, options);
   return mediaItem;
 }
```

You will call this method :

```
  MediaItem myFile = AddFile("c:\\myfile.pdf", "myfile", "/pdffolder/uploaded");
```

In your case you will have:

```
 var dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath("~/images/temp"));
 FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
 var list = new ArrayList();

 foreach (FileInfo file in files)
 {
    if (file.Extension == ".jpg" || file.Extension == ".jpeg" || file.Extension == ".gif" || file.Extension == ".png")
    {
        AddFile(file.FullName, file.Name, "/pdffolder/uploaded");
    }
 }
```

Details you can find here: 
   https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2009/07/09/adding-a-file-to-the-sitecore-media-library-programatically/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What does this line doing ` MediaItem mediaItem = creator.CreateFromFile("c:\\myfile.pdf", options);`

Comment: I updated my answer, is creating mediaitem from a given file.

Comment: I am using your code. But nothing is happening. I have updated my question as well. Can you plz check.

Comment: Did you check with debug if is calling my method?

Comment: Now Its Working. I got the mistake. I will update the question in few moments.

Comment: By the way where did you get this information. Can you please add a link to your question. So that others can also benefit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions to do this.

https://himadritechblog.wordpress.com/2015/05/02/bulk-loading-images-in-sitecore-media-library-using-sitecore-powershell-extension-spe/